# How to draw a chart for date wise row count

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

How can I create a chart in excel to show me how many records exist for each date?

For example, if my excel sheet contains multiple rows created every day with the "date" as first column, then I want to see how many rows generated every day in a bar chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a pivot graph. Do `Insert -> Pivot Table -> Pivot Graph`. Select your date as your row and as your value as `Count of Date` and there you go. Bar chart by date.

Comment: If I could give you more then one up vote I would.